# Using own classes inside razor code

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have in my funcs.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

public static class AuthData
{
    public const string USERNAME = "zheref";
    public const string PASSWORD = "Altairis";
}
```

And I'm trying to access the USERNAME and PASSWORD constants in my AuthData class from my Razor Code (auth.cshtml file):

```
@{    
if(IsPost)
{
    var u = Request.Form["username"];
    var c = Request.Form["password"];

    if(u == AuthData.USERNAME && c == AuthData.PASSWORD)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/default");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/logon");
    }
}
}
```

This is generating a Compilation Error:
"An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately."

If that's not the way I'm not sure how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: You probably just need a `@using` statement. If `AuthData` isn't in a namespace, then it ought to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your funcs.cs file in your App_Code folder, if it doesn't exist create it.  This assumes that all namespaces are resolvable and you don't need any using statements in your razor file.

Comment: Worked perfectly with the App_Code folder. Thanks so much